# Regular Expression PHP finding the number after a certain number of # characters

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have the following line:

```
09:00 23/02/2012#3.5#2.2#91#3.7#7.4#170#S#1033.1#(+1 Hpa / 3H).#0#3H##4.5#Plus de 2500m #6####00#### Brume.#
```

I want to find the first number or character after the 15th #
In this case, the number I'm looking for is 6.

In this example:

```
03:00 24/02/2012#8.9#5.5#79#3.7#5.55#190#S#1031.3#(-1.1 Hpa / 3H).#0#3H##10#300 et 600m#7####00#####
```

The number I'm looking for is 7.

But it's not always a number, for example in this line:

```
00:00 29/02/2012#3.3#-0.2#78##3.7##N#1023.6#(+0.3 Hpa / 3H).#0#3H##22#Plus de 2500m######### Le ciel est clair.#
```

The character after the 15th # is also a #.

So how can I get this number or character using PHP regular expressions?

I tried

```
$content = '09:00 23/02/2012#3.5#2.2#91#3.7#7.4#170#S#1033.1#(+1 Hpa / 3H).#0#3H##4.5#Plus de 2500m #6####00#### Brume.#';

$iparr = preg_split ("/#/", $content); 

echo $iparr[16];
```

But for the third example, it gives nothing. (because of the 2 consecutive #)

Comment: You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: I know it's preg_match !! but how ?

Comment: there is no need to use a regular expression for this - use `explode`

Comment: @maggie: You should state in your question what you have tried.

Comment: @ohaal : Ok I just edited the question to include what I have tried

Comment: @maggie what are you expecting for the 3nd example? empty string or '#' or what?

Comment: @ahaal I'm expecting a #.

Comment: But thanks, I think explode worked fine, just like they said in the solution

Comment: @maggie You can use the following regex pattern `(?:#.*?){15}(.)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `explode`.

```
$parts = explode('#', $string, 16);

$item = substr($parts[15], 0, 1);
```

And in PHP >= **5.4.0**, you can write it like this:

```
$string = '09:00 23/02/2012#3.5#2.2#91#3.7#7.4#170#S#1033.1#(+1 Hpa / 3H).#0#3H##4.5#Plus de 2500m #6####00#### Brume.#';
$index  =  16;

var_dump(explode('#', $string)[$index - 1]);
```

Comment: @Schleis Changed it, try now?

Comment: I tried it, for the first example it's giving me a # instead of 6. Probably something wrong with the indices???

Comment: @maggie just do `$parts[15][0]` instead of using `substr` (or `$item = substr($parts[15], 0, 1)` if you want

Comment: @maggie If you use your exact string, it should work. 16 and 15 are the indices.

Comment: @silkfire, you want the first character of the last string in the array, so `0, 1` should be the last two arguments to `substr`

Comment: @maggie Glad you liked my solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version using regex / `preg_match`

```
<?php
$str = "00:00 29/02/2012#3.3#-0.2#78##3.7##N#1023.6#(+0.3 Hpa / 3H).#0#3H##22#Plus de 2500m######### Le ciel est clair.#";
$match = array();
# match until 15 '#', grab the digit as well as a character
preg_match( "/(.*?#){15}([^\d]*(\d)|(.))/", $str, $match );
# the last element is the one containing best match, so just pop it
$char_after_15 = array_pop( $match );
print( $char_after_15 );
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two basic problems: (1) How to match a certain number of a given character when there can be other characters in between, and (2) how to retrieve what follows without retrieving everything.  [silkfire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170817/20938) is probably your best option, but here's how you can do it with a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:[^#]*#){15}(.)/', $subject, $match)) {
    $result = $match[1];
}
```

If you want to apply it to several strings at once, this should do it:

```
preg_match_all('/^(?:[^#]*#){15}(.)/', $subject, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $matches[1];
```

`$result` in this case is a one-dimensional array containing the contents of group #1 from every match.

**EDIT:** Upon reflection, it looks like the string is essentially a CSV record with `#` instead of `,` as the delimiter, and you want the number from the sixteenth field.  But the number is optional, so you grab whatever follows the fifteenth delimiter and if it's not a digit, you treat is as an empty field.  If that's the case, you might want to use this regex:

```
'/^(?:[^#]*#){15}(\d*)/'
```

This captures an empty string when there's no number, plus it will match a number with more than one digit, in case that matters.